# Hibernate: creating a unique GenerateValue for each relational record when inserting collections

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

I'm using Hibernate to insert entities like so:

I'm inserting a single `post` entity which owns a collection of `comment` entities. I'm trying to insert a new `post` with two new `comment` entities, but am unable to generate unique ids for each `comment` entity.

```
    // Create post.

    final String title = "unit test TITLE";
    final String content = "unit test CONTENT";

    Post post = new Post();

    post.setTitle(title);
    post.setContent(content);

    // Crate comments.

    final String author1 = "unit test AUTHOR 1";
    final String content1 = "unit test CONTENT 1";
    final String author2 = "unit test AUTHOR 2";
    final String content2 = "unit test CONTENT 2";

    Comment comment1 = new Comment();
    Comment comment2 = new Comment();

    comment1.setAuthor(author1);
    comment1.setContent(content1);
    comment2.setAuthor(author2);
    comment2.setContent(content2);

    // Add comments to post

    post.getComments().add(comment1);
    post.getComments().add(comment2);

    // Save posts.

    postRepository.save(post);
```

Each entity has an `id` field like so:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

Since the insert is done in a single transaction, the `id` for each comment is the same, resulting in the error:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "comments_pkey"
```

**How should I annotate or configure the `id` field in the `comment` entity such that I can insert multiple comments without using the same auto-generated ID for each?**

One solution I've thought of is using `UUID`s, but even then I'm not sure if they would be different.

Note: The default sequence comes from `hibernate_sequence`. It's not a problem that both records come from this sequence and I can get these sequences to come from their table specific sequences (`comment_id_seq` and `post_id_seq`), however this does not solve the problem of each comment being inserted with the same `id`.

Note: Doing the above insert while only inserting one comment does not cause the error.

Comment: 'Since the insert is done in a single transaction, the id for each comment is the same' - that's not how it works at all. Please post the `Post` and `Comment` entities, there might be  problem with your mapping

Comment: Also, share the DDL for the table Comment and entity mapping